# C++ constructor, destructor, type conversion error

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, destructor

Hey guys I am trying to create a implementation file for a module. It has a header file I created and a .CC file. In my .CC file I originally had a main function,  however as this is an assignment for a class, it requires there be no main function in the implementation.

```
  9 #include <curses.h>
 10 #include <sys/time.h>
 11 #include <time.h>
 12 #include "fmttime.h"
 13
 14
 15 struct ExpandedTime
 16 {
 17
 18     int et_usec;
 19     int et_sec;
 20     int et_min;
 21     int et_hour;
 22
 23 };
 24 ExpandedTime* localTime(struct timeval* tv, ExpandedTime* etime);
 25
 26
 27 struct timeval tv;
 28 struct ExpandedTime etime;
 29 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
 30 localTime(&tv,&etime);
 31
 32
 33
 34 ExpandedTime* localTime(struct timeval* tv, ExpandedTime* etime)
 35 {
 36     tzset();                                    // Corrects timezone
 37
 38     int epochT = (tv->tv_sec) - timezone;       // Epoch seconds with
 39     int epochUT = tv->tv_usec;                  // Timezone correction
 40
 41     int seconds = epochT % 60;
 42     epochT /= 60;
 43     etime->et_sec = seconds;
 44     etime->et_usec = epochUT;
 45
 46     int minutes = epochT % 60;
 47     epochT /= 60;
 48     etime->et_min = minutes;
 49
 50     int hours = (epochT % 24) + daylight;       // Hours with DST correction
```

Sorry the last few lines got cut off, copying and pasting off Mcedit in putty sucks. Anyways lines 29 and 30 are giving me a constructor, destructor or type conversion error and I can't figure out why. When I had a main function enclosing those statements all was fine and dandy...but when I removed the Main...it just broke down. Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: And what exactly did the "just broke down" entail?

Comment: The `gettimeofday` and `localTime` seems in the wrong scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
27 struct timeval tv;
28 struct ExpandedTime etime;
29 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
30 localTime(&tv,&etime);
```

This code isn't inside of any function. It's sitting bare naked out in the global scope wilderness. It needs to be shown back home, back inside a function, any function. There are wolves out there.

Comment: I see....heehe wolves. But the struct statements are fine..im assuming cause there just like a global variable but how come I can't call functions without being inside a function first? (if that makes sense)

Comment: @PresidentRFresh Because execution starts at main(), wherever main() is, and main() only calls other functions. There's no way to "call" this code.... Or, said another way: just because. Because I said so. Code goes inside functions.

Comment: Yes i figured that out haha. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks again for the help! I need to create another .cc file to test the implementation :)